# не получается с запросом ajax

Tags: php, ajax

вот в таком скрипте делаю валидацию но не работает, и ошибок нет, не могу понят почему...

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('#singin_sector').on('submit', function(event) { //вешаем на форму событие сабмит
    if ( validateForm() ) { // если есть ошибки возвращает true
        event.preventDefault(); // отменяем событие по умолчанию
        return false; // прерываем выполнение скрипта
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: "../system/forms.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {login: $("#signin-email").val(), password: $("#signin-password").val()},
      //Указываем что формат будет json
      dataType: 'json',
      //При успешном ответе принимаем значение json
      success: function(data){
        //Если данные есть, то...
        if(data){
            alert(data);
            //пытаемся заменить $that тем что получили
            $('#submit_singin_sector').after("<span>"+data+"</span>");
        }
      }
    });
  });

function validateForm() {
    $(".text-error").remove(); //удаляем этот элемент с когда страницы

    var el_e = $("#signin-email");
    var el_p1 = $("#signin-password");

    // Проверка e-mail
    var reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@(((([a-z0-9]{2,})|([a-z0-9][-][a-z0-9]+))[\.][a-z0-9])|([a-z0-9]+[-]?))+[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z]{2}|(com|net|org|edu|int|mil|gov|arpa|biz|aero|name|coop|info|pro|museum))$/i;

    var v_email = el_e.val()?false:true; //если поле пустое тогда ответ true иначе false

    if ( v_email ) {
        //Cразу после выбранных элементов будет добавлен content, который может быть задан html, объектом jQuery, DOM-объектом
        el_e.after('<span class="text-error for-email">Поле e-mail обязательно к заполнению</span>');
    } else if ( !reg.test( el_e.val() ) ) {
        v_email = true;
        el_e.after('<span class="text-error for-email">Вы указали недопустимый e-mail</span>');
    }

    // Проверка паролей
    if ( el_p1.val().length < 8 ) {
        var v_pass1 = true;
        el_p1.after('<span class="text-error for-pass1">Пароль должен быть не менее 8 символов</span>');
    } 
    return ( v_email || v_pass1 );
}
  });
```

валидация скрипта отрабатывается успешно, не работает только запрос ajax
ответ от сервера ...

```
if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {
   return json_encode("Ваш логин: ".$_POST['email'].", пароль: ".$_POST['pass']);
}
```

Comment: не `return` надо, а `echo`.....ну и `enter` вы в POST не передаете, только логин да пароль.....плюс передаете ключ `login` а потом пытаетесь вывести по ключу `email` -> `$_POST['email']`, аналогично с паролем

Comment: Я изменил dataType на html и data на $('#singin_sector').seriliaze(), начал выводиться ответ но после перезагрузки, т.е. открывается новыя страница и выводит ответ.

Comment: В своем обработчике `$('#singin_sector').on('submit', function(event) {` перед последним закрывающим `});` напишите: `return false;` - и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Ваш вариан  не помог

Comment: и ошибку возвращает undefined не знаю от чего и как исправить

Comment: и ошибку возвращает undefined не знаю от чего и как исправить
то что пишет в консоли:

send @ jquery.min.js:5
ajax @ jquery.min.js:5
(anonymous function) @ validateforms.js:8
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:4
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

спасибо разобрался! итак ...
java ...

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('#singin_sector').on('submit', function(event) { //вешаем на форму событие сабмит
    if ( validateForm() ) { // если есть ошибки возвращает true
        event.preventDefault(); // отменяем событие по умолчанию
        return false; // прерываем выполнение скрипта
    }

    var m_method=$(this).attr('method');
    //получаем адрес скрипта на сервере, куда нужно отправить форму
    var m_action=$(this).attr('action');
    //получаем данные, введенные пользователем в формате input1=value1&input2=value2...,
    //то есть в стандартном формате передачи данных формы
    var m_data=$(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: m_method,
        url: m_action,
        data: m_data,
        //При успешном ответе принимаем значение json
        success: function(data){
            //document.getElementById('server_respons').text("Ответ от сервера: "+data);
            //Если данные есть, то...
            if(data){
                //пытаемся заменить $that тем что получили
                $('#server_respons').html("Ответ от сервера: "+data);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            $('#server_respons').html('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode + ', status: ' + textStatus + ', errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
        }
    }); return false;
  });

function validateForm() {
    $(".text-error").remove(); //удаляем этот элемент с когда страницы

    var el_e = $("#signin-email");
    var el_p1 = $("#signin-password");

    // Проверка e-mail
    var reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@(((([a-z0-9]{2,})|([a-z0-9][-][a-z0-9]+))[\.][a-z0-9])|([a-z0-9]+[-]?))+[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z]{2}|(com|net|org|edu|int|mil|gov|arpa|biz|aero|name|coop|info|pro|museum))$/i;

    var v_email = el_e.val()?false:true; //если поле пустое тогда ответ true иначе false

    if ( v_email ) {
        //Cразу после выбранных элементов будет добавлен content, который может быть задан html, объектом jQuery, DOM-объектом
        el_e.after('<span class="text-error for-email">Поле e-mail обязательно к заполнению</span>');
    } else if ( !reg.test( el_e.val() ) ) {
        v_email = true;
        el_e.after('<span class="text-error for-email">Вы указали недопустимый e-mail</span>');
    }

    // Проверка паролей
    if ( el_p1.val().length < 8 ) {
        var v_pass1 = true;
        el_p1.after('<span class="text-error for-pass1">Пароль должен быть не менее 8 символов</span>');
    } 
    return ( v_email || v_pass1 );
}
return false;
});
```

php ...

```
if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {
   if ($_POST['email'] == "") {
       echo"Enter email!";
   } elseif ($_POST['pass'] == "") {
       echo "Enter pass!";
   } else {
       echo "Login: ".$_POST['email'].", pass: ".$_POST['pass'];
   }
}
```

скрипт работает и результат есть. НО! у меня теперь другой вопрос...
когда код php проверяет на if (isset($_POST['enter'])) { ... тогда php код не срабатывет через ajax потому что не передается $_POST['enter'], в случае если убрать эту проверку то все отрабатывает. теперь вопрос, если пользователь отключит в браузере javascript и не делать проверку if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {... то форма не будет отрабатываться, как это можно исправить????